# login auth check keeps returning false in laravel 4

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4

I'm creating a login system in laravel.  On my local server, the code works but when I put it on a live server, the Auth::check() keeps return false and thus when I login with the right credentials it redirects me back to login page again.  FYI My liver server is using php 5.4 while my local server is using php 5.5

Here is my code.

routes.php

```
    Route::get('/', function() {
//Auth::check() KEEPS RETURNING FALSE EVEN WHEN USER LOGS IN
                if (Auth::check() == true) {
                    $role = Auth::user()->role;
                    if ($role == 1) {
                        return View::make('administrator');
                    } elseif ($role == 9) {
                        return View::make('agent');
                    }
                } else {
                    return View::make('login');
                }
            });
```

LoginController.php

```
 public function login() {
        if (Auth::attempt(array('username' => Input::json('username'), 'password' => Input::json('password')))) {
            return Response::json(Auth::user());
        } else {

            return Response::json(array('flash' => 'Invalid email or password'), 500);
        }
    }
}
```

angularcontroller.js

```
    $scope.login = function() {
        //assign variables
        var post = {};
        post.username = $scope.info.username;
        post.password = $scope.info.password;

//Validation
        var errors = 0;


        if (errors == 0) {
            loginServ.login(post).then(function(data) {
                if (data.status == 500) {
                    alert('wrong username or password');
                } else {
                    window.location.replace("");
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

angular_service.js

```
login_module.factory('loginServ', function($http, $q) {
    return {
        login: function(post) {

            var url =  "login/login";
            return $q.all([
                $http.post(url, {
                    username: post.username,
                    password: post.password
                })
            ])
                    .then(function(results) {
                var data = [];
                angular.forEach(results, function(result) {
                    data = data.concat(result.data);
                    //  console.log("data: "+result);
                    // console.log("result.data: "+result.data);
                });

                return data[0];
            },
                    function(error) {
                        console.log(error.status);
                        return error;
                        // Handle error here
                    });

        }
    }
});
```

I have login form using angularjs.  It sends a POST request and if it gets a 200 response then it sends a GET request to "/".  However even with right login credentials it keeps going back to the same login page.

Thanks

Comment: can you share URL for login request from angularJS?

Comment: updated example to show angular code

Comment: what are your 'session' settings?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the value in app\config\session.php => 'cookie'.
This should fix the issue